# IF (VLOOKUP greater then number) then fetch value from same row in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, dax

After reading multiple posts on this forum and others without having any success or finding similar problems I've decided to try my luck with my own post. I will try to explain the problem to the best of my ability without pictures from excel. Hope you'll understand.

I have two sheets.

### Sheet 1

```
ProductID | Period |  Comment 
   123      2.test   This is bad
   524      2.test   This is bad
   123      3.test   This is bad
   123      3.test   This is bad
   123      4.test   This is good
   123      4.test   This is good
```

### Sheet 2

```
   Comment    | ProductID
 This is bad       123
```

What I want to do is fetch the **comment** from Sheet1 based on the **ProductID** from Sheet2. However, I only want the comment if the number in the **period** column is greater then 3. For example "2.test" is not ok, but "4.test" is fine.

My current DAX formula (located in the **Comment** column in Sheet2) is described below. Worth mentioning, since it's not clear from my illustration of the sheets, is that **B2** is the cell containing 123 in the ProductID column in Sheet2.

```
=IF(LEFT(VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10;2;FALSE))>3;VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10;3;FALSE);x)
```

This formula only works halfway. The condition in the IF formula is working. However, the "value/action if true" is the part I have issue with. After finding the correct **productID** where the "X.test" is greater then 3 I want to fetch the comment on that row. I'm currently using VLOOKUP again, but that will only find the comment associated with the first productID it finds, not if the period in the same row is greater then 3.

The result I'm looking for is "This is good" in Sheet2 in the column **Comment**.

I have tried using match, row and index. However the combination between them might not been right. The solution might just be right in front of my eyes without realizing it.

If the case is not clear please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `LEFT` is missing the argument for number of characters. You also need to wrap the `LEFT` with a `VALUE` to make the `>` expression meaningful. Assuming that's a real formula and not just a standin, you also need `"x"` rather than `x` as your final value_if_false expression. Though, as you say, all of that is a bit immaterial as even as a functional formula, the `VLOOKUP` as you've expressed it is not a suitable approach to your task.

Comment: You may find [this](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-index-match-multiple-criteria-multiple-results/) to be useful

Answer (score 0):

I added a `IFERROR` in case `VLOOKUP` doesn´t find the ID. As stated by @Alex M, you where missing the number of returned chars.

```
if(left(iferror(vlookup(B2;Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10;2;0);1);1)>3;vlookup(B2;Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10;2;0);x)
```

Hope this helps
Cheers